# refactoring array looped around another arrary for assignment

Tags: php, class, refactoring

I know this is more of PHP problem because of it's loose Typing of arrays but I see this problem all over the place in a project I took over and not sure of the best way to refactor it. Suppose you have two sets of data, both multi dimensional arrays, $results_by_entity and $target_limits and we want to check what the target is foreach result_by_entity so we can set some state

```
foreach ($results_by_entity AS $result_by_entity) {
  foreach ($target_limits AS $target_limit) {
      if ($target_limit['activity_id'] == $result_by_entity['activity_id']) {
          $result_by_entity->target = $target_limit->quantity;
          $result_by_entity->progress = $target_limit->score;
      }
 }
```

}

There are a couple of main problems here

1-The data is really strongly tied together, so it is really hard to refactor $results_by_entity into it's own class and $target_limits into it's own class
2-The time taken to process this grows exponentially as the data size grows

I read the Refactoring book by Martin Fowler and it was really helpful but this style of problem doesn't really show up I think mostly because his examples are in JAVA which is strongly typed. The class is super run on so really hard to debug and extend but all the data is so tied together primarily because of these types of loops so not to sure how to solve. Any recommendations would be really appreciated

Comment: You want to easily join the two arrays on "activity_id" and process the data from one to the other keeping performance in mind, is that it?

Comment: yeah thanks, thats' it, I have simplified it down quite a bit as there are a lot of extra variables involved. I have one huge class and lots of big sets of data in it which are all stored as multi-dimension arrays and then this style of processing the data between arrays is used a lot and it has made it really entangled.

Comment: The best way to refactor here is to perform a `JOIN` so that all data comes in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to index your data pre-emptively if possible:

```
$results_index = array();
foreach ($results_by_entity AS $result_by_entity) {

    //Index this value
    $results_index[$result_by_entity['activity_id']] = $result_by_entity; //Add a & in front if it's a scalar value, but it looks like it's an object in your example

}

foreach ($target_limits AS $target_limit) {

    //Find the corresponding activity id in results
    if (isset($results_index[$target_limit['activity_id']])) {
        $result_by_entity = $results_index[$target_limit['activity_id']];
        $result_by_entity->target = $target_limit->quantity;
        $result_by_entity->progress = $target_limit->score;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats the best you can do if you can't/don't want to do it use a SQL server

Comment: thanks, that is a clearer way of splitting it up for sure. It is all coming from an SQL database and we have tried doing all the calculation on the database but it became so slow. I understand it was and tests still show it to quicker to take the data in and then process it into a few diferrent arrays in PHP as opposed to calculating all the logic in SQL. I'm justing having issues keeping the code modularized.